# Using UIWebView to render images instead of UIImageView in iOS uses much less memory. Makes sense?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, uiimage, ios

I just figured out that - instead of using a `UIImageView` to show an image - I use an `UIWebView`, it uses much less memory. Does that make sense for anyone?

What I did was to get an ordinary .jpg file with about 280kb in size and show it on a simple app with just an `UIImageView`. Looking at Instrument's Object Allocations tool, the application's memory footprint was about 3MB.

Then I removed the `UIImageView` and added an `UIWebView` with the following code:

```
NSString *html = @"<html><body style='margin:0;'><img src='my_test_image.jpg'></body></html>";
[web loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
```

and then the memory usage dropped to around 700kb.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I suspect your 3MB instrument:)

Answer (score 1):

The UIWebView scale your image and crop it (When it is higher than the screen size...) It is an optimization from Apple in order to easily print every image on a website with less memory usage... The image quality change with the image size.

The UIImageView doesn't have that kind of optimization.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will have such a major difference, even the oldest iPod Touch has 128MB of RAM. Just alloc and release it all correctly and you should be fine either way.